# How to use the python jira-cli --extra option?

Tags: python, jira, jira-cli

I tried to use the python jira-cli client "https://github.com/alisaifee/jira-cli" to specify the extra field duedate:

```
jira-cli new --project SYSENG --type "Service Request" --extra "duedate=01/01/2018" --protocol rest test
```

or

```
jira-cli new --project SYSENG --type "Service Request" --extra "{'duedate': '01/Dec/18'}" --protocol rest test
```

In no way I can get the ticket created because in my Jira the Due Date is required.

I didn't find a way in the official [Doc](https://jira-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)
Do you know any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually after some digging I found how the date should be formatted in jira package at client.py at line 1368 is stated:

> based on REST Browser it needs: "2014-06-03T08:21:01.273+0000"

Therefore I tried with:

```
jira-cli new --project SYSENG --type story "This is a test story" --description='description' --extra "duedate=2018-01-01" -v
```

and it worked.